# Git: Checkout a file from another branch to working tree only in one go

Tags: git

In Git, I can checkout out a file from another branch with:

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -- <path spec>
```

And this updates the index and the working tree with that file. To unstage the file I then have to:

```
git reset HEAD -- <path spec>
```

Is there a way to do this in a single step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's optimal but `git show treeish:path > path` should work.

Comment: +1 This works; it does feel a bit hacky though - I'll accept if nothing better comes today! Thanks.

Comment: It's "reasonably close to optimal".  As VonC noted in another thread, it skips the smudge filter, though.

Comment: Good point. The fact that it's not git but the shell that is updating the working tree is important.